# How to normalize a large, user-generated data-set of company names

Tags: apex

I would like to know is there a way in salesforce to normalize a large, user-generated data-set of company names

We have user generated names of employers that come in all variations. For example, people have typed in or imported:

Google
Google, Inc.
Google Inc.
Google inc

Does anyone have suggestions on how to normalize the existing entries, and also how to maintain we do it for all incoming names as well?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to handle this is to export it to Excel. It's fast and user friendly.

The actual data cleaning you need to do depends on your data but from your example, you can do the following.

1) You can do a replace (via a formula) that any cell that has the word google in it, replace with Google Inc so every instance of Google will end up being consistent. Then you import it into SF.

2) You could also parse the names using spaces, commas and tabs as delimiters so the name Google will be in one column by itself and then you could sort and choose which columns to import into SF.

You can use dataloader, or jitterbit to load your data. There are other options as well.

If you need more clarification, please ask.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but exporting into Excel file is not really an option for me. Is there a way for the company name normalization to be done programatically?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. I didn't think of this sooner.

Comment: You can create a "Flow" to get a collection of records that contain a string like "oogle" which would contain most (if not all) of your examples above and then have it iterate through the collection and rename to Google (or however you want to clean it.) D

Comment: Sorry, I keep hitting the "Enter'Key to get a new line. Of course, this can be done in APEX if you know how code. Did that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, right now your users enter these name as a plain  text. In this case you need to define a dedicated object for storing information about  employers. I think `Epmloyer__c` is a good name for this object.

The second step is to create a script which will convert employer names into records of `Employer__c`. After you need a script which will look for duplicates and merge it into a single record. This script should be pretty simple.

something like that:

** I assume that you store this information in Contact records in custom field `Employer__c`*

```
List<Employer__c> employers = new List<Employer__c>();
List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Employer__c FROM Contact];
for (Contact c: contacts) {
    employers.add(new Employer__c(Name = c.Employer__c));
}
insert employers;
```

In case of large data set you need to use Batch Apex.

The last step is creation of mechanism which will prevent a duplication of `Employer__c` records. You can create your own solution as well as check AppExchange or use [standard Salesforce.com approach](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm).

After that your users can use single company names base which will be available via lookup relationship in any object where you want to create it.

Comment: No, this is not what I want to achieve. I would like to be able to normalize large set of user generated company names. Google Google, Inc. Google Inc. Google inc. To a database search this, looks like a different company. So what I basically need is the name of the company without its extension which in this case is 'Inc'